# python: least-squares estimation?

Tags: python, matrix, numerical-methods

I know how to implement least-squares with elementary matrix decomposition and other operations, but how can I do it in Python? (I've never tried to use matrices in Python)

---

(clarification edit to satisfy the shoot-first-and-ask-questions-later -1'er)

I was looking for help to find out how to use numerical programming in Python. Looks like numpy and scipy are the way to go. I was looking for how to *use* them, but I found a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy` and `numpy` is the obvious way to go here.

Note that `numpy` uses the famous (and well-optimized) BLAS libraries, so it is also very fast. Much faster than any "pure python" will ever be.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SciPy.  It's got matrix operations.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, [this tutorial for numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) gives me a good starting point.